# SignalR java client can't invoke method and send data

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I created a basic selfhosted SignalR server with the following code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

Which is taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host and works with the Javascript client.

I am now trying to create a Java client and got the following code that is simply supposed to send a message to the server:

```
       String host = "http://localhost:8080";

        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(host);

        HubProxy proxy = connection.createHubProxy("MyHub");

        connection.start();

        try {
            System.out.println("Sendng message...");
            proxy.invoke( "Send", "Client", "Hello world!" ).get();
            System.out.println("Message sent!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("err1");
            // Handle ...
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("err2");
            // Handle ...
        }
```

The problem that im having is that the message is not received by the server, it seems like the code is stuck at the invoke call and doesn't print the `Hello world!` message. Does someone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: There's already a Java client for SignalR - https://github.com/SignalR/java-client . Can you use that instead?

Comment: @ADyson Hmm which one do you mean because all I can see are test files?

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/java-client#using-the-library-in-a-java-application ?

Comment: @ADyson I already have the java files imported in the project, do I need to create a jar file? I am not that good with java and brand new to signalr so sorry if I ask simple questions.

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I've not been a Java dev for 15 years...this popped up in my feed because of the asp.net tag. I just did one quick google and thought you could investigate further. I assumed they were referring to a file already existing in the repo, but yeah maybe you have to build it.

Answer (score 0):

```
hubProxy.invoke("sendMessageByUser", Message, WebApiToken).done(new Action<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void run(Void aVoid) {


            if (aVoid != null)

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(MyApplicationService.this, "Mesaj gönderildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });


        }
    }).onError(new ErrorCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable error) {


            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(MyApplicationService.this.getApplicationContext(), "Bir hata oluştu" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        }
    });
```